# How to cite a subchapter of a book with correct notation

Tags: biblatex

I have a book in which I'm trying to reference to several different pages containing information on different subjects, see the added current bib-section below. So for example, I want to refer to pages 1008-1014 in one paragraph and pages 258 in another paragraph. I've seen some people who get the note "70a" and "70c" when they are citing these, but I only get "70" on both and I can't figure out how to get the proper citation. Can anybody help? :)

Let's say this is reference 70:

```
@book{synteseenbok,
    author = {\text{Carey, F. A. and Sundberg, R. J.}},
    Edition = {5th},
    Publisher = {Springer: New York},
    Title = {Advanced organic synthesis. Part B: Reactions and Synthesis},
    Year = {2007},
    note = {a: 1008-1014, b: 1030-1032, c: 258}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Citation practices can vary from field to field. In most fields that I'm familiar with, you would add a book entry to the bibliography only once without any page references. You would then give the page references directly in the citation (i.e. when you cite the book).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{synteseenbok,
  author    = {Carey, F. A. and Sundberg, R. J.},
  maintitle = {Advanced organic synthesis},
  title     = {Reactions and Synthesis},
  volume    = {B},
  year      = {2007},
  edition   = {5},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location  = {New York},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[1008-1014]{synteseenbok}
ipsum \autocite[1030-1032]{synteseenbok}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1, pp. 1008–1014] ipsum [1, pp. 1030–1032]]